# Does not work onPause() in the ViewPager fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-lifecycle, android-tablayout

I have a problem:
I use ViewPager+ TabLayout with NavigationView
I call ViewPager from the fragment.

My problem: the onPause() method in the child fragment is not called.
When the application starts, all methods (onStart(), onActivityCreated()) are triggered.
When destroy app, the methods only work in the fragment in which I call ViewPager шn child fragments, onPause(), onStope() does not work.
I think the problem is that the destruction of the parent fragment occurs faster than the child fragment.

This is the code of my fragment in which I call ViewPager.

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fr_four, container, false);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 1"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Tab 2"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });


    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FragmentFour.onCreateView()",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Log.d("FragmentFour", "onCreateView");

    return view;
}


    public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    int mNumOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                FragmentFourOne tab1 = new FragmentFourOne();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                FragmentFourTwo tab2 = new FragmentFourTwo();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

How to fix it?
I will be glad to any help.
Thank.

Answer (score 1):

After so many days, I found the answer.
Everything works if `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` is replaced with `getChildFragmentManager()`.

here is the final code

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
adapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```